# Cloudflare - How to hide website's server IP address from the beginning itself?

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

There's a website `example.com` served at `1.2.3.4`

Currently you need to point your registrar's DNS to `1.2.3.4`
Then you need to add your site to cloudflare .
And then you need to change the DNS records at registrar to point to Cloudflare DNS.New cloudflare IP returned during DNS query is `5.6.7.8` But if an attacker(or a user) accessed the website when it didn't have cloudflare protection, they can still have the old ip `1.2.3.4` and attack it.

How to hide the origin server IP from the beginning itself (before the site is launched?) so that `1.2.3.4` is hidden from the moment site comes online?

Comment: The site itself never has to be online for you to set it up in Cloudflare. So it's possible to just buy the domain, never add any record to it, set the nameserver to Cloudflare, then add the orange record, which only then point to an actual IP

Comment: Thanks martheen! Write this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy the domain, don't add any record to it yet, set the nameserver to Cloudflare, and only then add the orange record, which point to an actual IP

Comment: You still need to block non-cloudflare IPs otherwise the IP will still be accessible through crawlers and what not.

Comment: I agree with you Philips.. I was just wondering if the IP can be hidden from the beginning

Comment: @PhilipsKuyper It would help, dropping requests without SNI works too, port scanner probing my VPS will only see a cert for invalid domain with empty response.

Answer (score 2):

block the port for non-cloudflare IP ranges

Comment: Is there any other way?